# Energy question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, newtonian-gravity

It is from an exam but it's worth going on here

[image: processed image]

I know the answer from the mark scheme. but I don't know why

To be honest, they all look like true statements to me...

Comment: Which of the statements are you unsure about?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems.](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301)

Comment: Scott, this is a site for conceptual questions about physics, not a place for you to offload every single past exam question that you've ever had trouble with. Please read Kyle's links carefully.

Comment: Ok thanks I am going to still post these questions here because it is helping me with physics so much, but I will begin to word them in such a way as to help other people. (Ie make it more general).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that at terminal velocity the parachutist is traveling at a **constant** velocity( the terminal velocity) so thus the velocity of the parachutist is **not** increasing.$$E_k=1/2mv^2$$ Here $m$(mass of parachutist) is constant and $v$ is also constant( velocity of parachutist).  Thus, the parachutist's kinetic energy is **not** increasing. So thus **B** is the correct answer.

Note: As the gravitational potential energy of the parachutist *is* decreasing as he/she falls so thus must be converted to forms other than kinetic energy of the parachutist as his/her velocity is constant. Thus, the gravitational potential energy can turn into thermal energy( i.e. Kinetic energy of air) and also thermal energy(i.e. Kinetic energy of the molecular vibrations in parachutist **not** the body as a whole).

Comment: Awesome thank you so much. By the way I have no idea why my question has a downvote?

Comment: I did not give the downvote but it is probably because in Physics SE Homework questions are generally considered off topic. So next time if you ask, detail on your question about the physics concepts you do not understand in relation to your question.

Comment: As in this site it's about your question being helpful not only to you but also to others who may want to understand a concept better.